# ¿Cómo puedo asignar una ruta en otro PC de manera automatica?

Tags: c#

Hay alguna manera de direccionar automaticamente la URL de un archivo?
Un ejemplo de esto sería:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string archivo = @"E:\Nueva carpeta (2)\Proyecto V4\Proyecto Sin Nada\MODERN_GUI_2\bin\Debug\test1.txt";
    File.Delete(archivo);
    MessageBox.Show("El evento a sido eliminado exitosa mente");
}
```

Si voy a utilizar el Software en otro PC me lanzaría error porque la dirección URL de los otros PC es distinta, ¿Hay alguna manera de que el archivo se quede con una URL especifica para que no edite cada vez que quiera utilizar mi software en otro PC?

Comment: ¿cual es el nombre de tu proyecto? ¿en que ruta esta realmente tu proyecto? revisa en tus apuntes o busca por internet temas relacionados con `rutas relativas`.  En tu caso probablemente tengas que utilizar algo como `.\MODERN_GUI_2\bin\Debug\test1.txt`, pero no puedo asegurartelo asi de primeras

Comment: Voy a buscar en Internet. Muchas gracias.

Comment: URL es una direccion de internet, no un path del disco rigido. si no sabes donde va a estar el archivo, vas a tener que preguntarlo. Si no, usa rutas relativas.

Comment: Con qué lo puedo preguntar?, o también puedo usar, <Application.StartupPath>

Answer (score 0):

Sí lo que necesitas es encontrar la ruta donde esta o estará instalado tu proyecto puedes buscar con **Environment.CurrentDirectory** aunque esto te dará la ruta del directorio donde está el ejecutable (BIN), para lo cual necesitarías es retroceder de directorio con **Parent** hasta encontrar el directorio que necesitas.

Es necesaria la librería `using System.IO;`

```
DirectoryInfo   directory   =   new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
string nombreDirectorio     =   directory.Name; // Nombre del directorio actual
string rutaCompleta         =   directory.FullName; // Toda la ruta
```

Con este método podrías buscar hasta los tres últimos directorios inmediatos superiores hasta encontrar el directorio que buscas, y no importa en qué nivel se encuentre, te retornará la ruta completa cuando la haya encontrado.

```
public string GetPath()
{
    DirectoryInfo   directory   =   new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    DirectoryInfo   parentDirectory;

    string ruta =   string.Empty;
    string directorioBuscado    =   string.Empty;   // Nombre del directorio el cual se quiere encontrar

    if (directory.Name == directorioBuscado)
        ruta    =   directory.FullName;
    else
    {
        if (directory.Parent.Name == directorioBuscado)
        {
            parentDirectory =   directory.Parent;
            ruta            =   parentDirectory.FullName;
        }
        else
        {
            if (directory.Parent.Parent.Name == directorioBuscado)
            {
                parentDirectory =   directory.Parent.Parent;
                ruta            =   parentDirectory.FullName;
            }
            else
            {
                if (directory.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name == directorioBuscado)
                {
                    parentDirectory =   directory.Parent.Parent.Parent;
                    ruta            =   parentDirectory.FullName;
                }
                else
                    ruta    =   "No se puede encontrar la ruta.";
            }
        }
    }
    return ruta;
}
```